# Git pull request multiple branches but other branch'es commits were added

Tags: git, github

I created branch `victor-boos-833`, worked on it, then push to origin as a new branch, then made a pull request.

I then created another branch `victor-order-error-code` from `master` (I think), worked on it, then push to origin as a new branch. The problem is, changes in `victor-boos-833` which has not been merged, were also shown in the origin `victor-order-error-code` branch. So the pull request on `victor-order-error-code` includes changes in `victor-boos-833`.

I checked my local, it's clean. Changes in `victor-boos-833` doesn't show in my `victor-order-error-code` branch. How can I fix this?

[image: Gitk branch tree]

Comment: It probably *should* show those changes. Look at the screenshot you included: the commit at the tip of `victor-boos-833` is the parent of the commit at the tip of `victor-order-error-code`.

Comment: Seems like you checked out `victor-order-error-code` from `victor-boos-833` and not `master`.

Comment: @Jin Probably that's my problem. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On your `victor-order-error-code` branch, run

`git revert SHA`

where SHA is the SHA hash(es) of the commits that you would like to remove.

You can specify a range of SHA hashes and it should be your entire `victor-boos-833` branch since `master`.

See http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#pushed_new_simple